# How to read directory structure as a API

Tags: php, api, rest

If you are writing a typical php script it lives in the directory you point the url to. An API responds to requests to directories down the tree like /api/feeds/80320. I assume the php code exists in the api directory and it reads that it got a request from /feeds/80320. How does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Redirect ALL your requests to one php script.**

In apache you can do that like this >

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

Then in PHP script parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` and do your magic.